# Move product review before quantity on product detail page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have override `product.info.review` block and now I want to display my output before quantity field . This is the code of `catalog_product_view` file for move this but it is not working

Comment: <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.price.final"/>

Comment: Hello @usman please check my answer below, I hope it would solve your problem of moving element https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284705/move-product-review-before-quantity-on-product-detail-page-in-magento-2/284718#284718

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code, it will move review block just before the `product.info` block and `product.info` block  contains quantity and addtocart button

```
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info"/>
```

Please make sure, you are editing in correct layout xml, sometimes same element is already moving by any other theme.
For example `product.info.review` is already move by `luma` theme

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Basically i have over-right review block and attached a template to it and in template file i display numeric values which i want to display before quantity .above solution is not working

Comment: Could you please write here the code of your xml and phtml file, along with their location?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Extension_Newmodule::counter.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
 <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.price.final"/>
 </body>
</page>

Comment: and my file named catalog product view with location /maentoroot/app/code/Extension/Newmodule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: It means, your theme has also move this element....
Please check in your theme's `catalog_product_view.xml` , is there <move> defined for `product.info.review` ?

In my case it was defined in `/var/www/html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Its written like:
`<move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>`

I have commented this above line, and then used your code in Extension_Newmodule , now its working fine.

Please check it at your end too, it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot,i got your point .But i have also found another solution .i am providing the code below by which other can also get benefited form it.
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
  <referenceContainer name="content">
   <container name="product.custom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-"><block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.custom.reivew" template="Extension_Newmodule::counter.phtml" />
  </container></referenceContainer><move element="product.custom.reivew" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info"/>

Comment: Explanation of code is first i remove it by referencing the block name .After that over right it and change its name and then it solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way as well. Good to know that you got solution. @usman if you feel that solution given by me is helpful, then please like my answer.

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation .when i tried to up vote your answer it display me a message that  your vote is recorded and but not displayed

Comment: As I checked, you have 16 reputations, could you please try once more to vote my answer?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out .i am going to up-vote your answer